# I'm an Irish citizen living in a different EU country, can I use my foreign ID if it has my Irish nationality on it

Tags: ireland, identity-cards, estonia

I'm just asking out of curiosity.
I'm an Irish citizen currently living in Estonia. I have an Estonian ID card which has my Irish nationality on the card. Can I use this card to enter Ireland and can I use this card to reenter Estonia?

Comment: I believe that there has been an EUCJ case stating that an ID issued by an EU country to a resident citizen of another EU country can indeed be used for travel under the free movement directive, but I am not certain of it. I do not see it on the [document information page at eur-lex](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32004L0038).  It's possible that the decision came from some other court.  I suppose that to be useful for such a purpose, the ID must note the bearer's nationality, which yours does. I would try to avoid having to rely on the Estonian card, if possible.

Comment: @phoog Thanks. I'm not planning on traveling with it alone. But I've said in comments here there the Irish passport is the only photo document that states Irish nationality. I believe it is but I had not considered foreign issued documents. It's a little bit interesting that there are ID's that proove Irish citizen ship but none of them are issued by Ireland (other than passport).

Comment: There's also the [passport card](https://www.dfa.ie/passportcard/), of course, though perhaps you are including it when you say "passport."  It seems that (unlike a US passport card) one cannot have an Irish passport card unless one also holds an Irish passport (i.e., in the traditional booklet form), but it is a separate photo document that proves Irish citizenship.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Not a duplicate. This question is about using a residence card from another country to get into your country of citizenship; the other question is explicitly about using the residence card to get into a third country, which is not the country of citizenship.

Comment: @phoog You are correct. You need to hold an Irish Passport to apply for an Irish Passport Card. The card lasts for 5 years, or until the expiry of the passport (whichever is the earliest). It also costs half the price of the passport. The main advantage is that it is credit-card sized, but it can only be used to travel within the EU/EEA/Schengen zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your Estonian ID card will be sufficient for travel to Ireland.

First, while your ID card does state that you are a national of Ireland, it is not *authoritative*, because Estonia does not have the authority to declare that you are an Irish citizen. Only Ireland has that authority.

Second, Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify travel documents, does not list this ID card as sufficient for Irish citizens to enter Ireland. Timatic currently states with regard to Irish citizens:

> Passport required.
>
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to nationals of Ireland (Rep.) must be valid on arrival.
>
> Passport Exemptions:
>
> - Nationals of Ireland (Rep.) with a passport card.
> - Passengers with a proof of nationality issued to nationals of Ireland (Rep.) and British subjects for travel between Ireland (Rep.) and Great Britain and Northern Ireland only.

As soon as the airline enters in that you are an Irish citizen, this will come up, and the Estonian ID card is not listed here.

Critically, Timatic says the same thing for the return journey, regarding the passport you must carry.

If you haven't got your passport or passport card, you should obtain one. You can [apply for it online](https://www.dfa.ie/passportonline/) and have it delivered to you (or to the embassy) in Estonia.